# Is it possible to read xlsx in react if office is not installed on windows machine?

Tags: reactjs, excel

Currently I am using below code to read xlsx file in react when my system having office (excel) installed. But the same is throwing error on other machine where office(excel) is not installed.

Error is at this point `console.log(this.state.file.type)`

Here is console.log :

```
lastModified: 1595606065652
lastModifiedDate: Fri Jul 24 2020 15:54:25 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) {}
name: "ExamAnswer.xlsx"
size: 14266
type: "" // here type is null
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

So, could you please tell how to read file type

```
handleExamInputFile() {
const reader = new FileReader();
const rABS = !!reader.readAsBinaryString;
console.log("file", this.state.file);

console.log(this.state.file.type);
let fileType =
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
if (this.state.file.size > 0) {
  console.log(this.state.file.size);

  if (this.state.file.type === fileType) {
    if (rABS) {
      reader.readAsBinaryString(this.state.file);
    } else {
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.state.file);
    }

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const bstr = e.target.result;
      const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, {
        type: rABS ? "binary" : "array",
        bookVBA: true,
      });

      const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {
        raw: true,
      });

      const header = [];
      const columnCount = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws["!ref"]).e.c + 1;
      for (let i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
        if (ws[`${XLSX.utils.encode_col(i)}1`] != undefined) {
          header[i] = ws[`${XLSX.utils.encode_col(i)}1`].v;
        }
      }
      console.log(header);
      let headerMustHave = ["Exam Name", "EId", "Name"];
      // let ifFound = header.every(function (val) {
      //   console.log(val);
      //   return headerMustHave.indexOf(val) !== -1;
      // });
      let checker = (arr, target) => target.every((v) => arr.includes(v));
      let ifFound = checker(header, headerMustHave);
      console.log(ifFound);
      if (ifFound === true) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          let excel_date = this.ExcelDateToJSDate(data[i]["Report Date"]);

          data[i]["Report Date"] = excel_date;
        }

        this.setState({
          data: data,
          result: JSON.stringify(data),
          cols: make_cols(ws["!ref"]),
        });

        const exceldata = JSON.parse(this.state.result);

        const excelList = exceldata.map((data) => data);

        const excel = { data: excelList };
        const url = "http://localhost:8000/upload";
        const config = {
          headers: {
            Accept: "*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            // Accept: "application/json",
          },
        };
        return post(url, excel, config).then((response) => {
          toast.success(response.data, {
            position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          });
          document.getElementById("file1").value = "";
          this.setState({ file: "" });
        });
      } else {
        toast.error("Some columns are not presented in uploaded file.", {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          autoClose: 3000,
        });
        this.setState({ file: "" });
      }
    };
  } else {
    toast.error(
      "This file format is not supported. Please select an .xlsx file.",
      {
        position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
        autoClose: 3000,
      }
    );
    this.setState({ file: "" });
  }
} else {
  toast.error("Please select .xlsx file to upload.", {
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
    autoClose: 3000,
  });
  this.setState({ file: "" });
 }
}
```

Alternatively, is it possible to read the same xlsx file through python on above type machine?

TIA

Comment: You want [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Your browser isn't _possibly_ using Excel installed on the computer. What is the particular error you're getting on the machine where things don't work?

Comment: InspectorG4dget any working ref if u could provide, will be very much helpful. I read about it previously but didn't give much time that time. But I will check . Also, if u can tell any react side xlax reader about) then it would be again very informative.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget : I have added my comments above.

Comment: @AKX : it usages I can tell you from the experience. As above code is working expected ( reading and saving excel data). I also don't want to create code on dependencies like these. For example if I want to deploy it on server (linux or windows) then there will not many software (IIS, notepad, browser are probably only). Regarding error: The error is : file type= " ". See my console log above

Comment: That just means they browser doesn't have a type mapping for Excel files. Try `file.name.endsWith("xlsx")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is React.js code, it's running client-side, in a browser.

Your problem with `type` being empty is that not all machines and browsers know how to map the file type `.xlsx` to the MIME type `'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'`; those with Excel, or maybe LibreOffice installed, certainly might, but even that's not a given. Whether or not Excel is actually installed has no bearing on whether the XLSX.js library you're using can actually parse the file (since the browser doesn't know about Excel).

As I mentioned in the comments, you can simply optionally look at the extension of the file uploaded – and even that's not necessary; you could just attempt to pass the file to XLSX; it would fail to parse files that are not XLSX documents anyway.

Here's a refactoring of your code to move to promise-based asynchronicity, moving the actual processing code out of the React component, so it's more easily testable.

In addition, you seemed to be doing some strange to-JSON-from-JSON coercion before posting the data; I got rid of that (and all of the Toast error handling for a more minimal example)...

```
function ExcelDateToJSDate(x) {
  return x; // TODO: implement
}

function processWorkbook(wb) {
  const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
  const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
  const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {
    raw: true,
  });

  const header = [];
  const columnCount = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws["!ref"]).e.c + 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
    const col = `${XLSX.utils.encode_col(i)}1`;
    if (ws[col] != undefined) {
      header[i] = ws[col].v;
    }
  }
  console.log(header);
  const headerMustHave = ["Exam Name", "EId", "Name"];
  const checker = (arr, target) => target.every((v) => arr.includes(v));
  let ifFound = checker(header, headerMustHave);
  if (ifFound === true) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let excel_date = ExcelDateToJSDate(data[i]["Report Date"]);
      data[i]["Report Date"] = excel_date;
    }
  }
  return { ws, data };
}

/**
 * Read a DOM File into a binary string or array buffer; returns a Promise.
 */
function readFile(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    let type;
    if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      type = "binaryString";
    } else {
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      type = "arrayBuffer";
    }
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      resolve({ type, data: event.target.result });
    };
    reader.onerror = (event) => reject(event);
  });
}

async function processExamInputFile(file) {
  if (!file) {
    throw new Error("No file selected.");
  }
  if (
    !(
      file.type === "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" ||
      file.name.endsWith(".xlsx")
    )
  ) {
    throw new Error("Invalid file type or extension.");
  }
  const { data, type } = await readFile(file);
  const wb = XLSX.read(data, {
    type: type === "binaryString" ? "binary" : "array",
    bookVBA: true,
  });
  return processWorkbook(wb);
}

class X {
  async handleExamInputFile() {
    try {
      const { ws, data } = await processExamInputFile(this.state.file);
      this.setState({
        data: data,
        result: JSON.stringify(data),
        cols: make_cols(ws["!ref"]),
      });
      await post(
        "http://localhost:8000/upload",
        { data },
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: "*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          },
        },
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);  // TODO: improve
    }
  }
}
```